# A word for something which covers the eyelid of horses and lead them to run straight

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, vocabulary

I am looking for a word for a thing that covers the eyelid of horses and lead the horses to run straight without track distractions.

Something similar to funambulist.

Comment: A *funambulist* is a 'tight-rope walker'. I think the word you are looking for is *blinkers*.

Comment: Or [blinders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkers_(horse_tack))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean [blinkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkers_%28horse_tack%29)/blinders?

> Blinkers, sometimes known as blinders, are a piece of horse tack that prevent the horse seeing to the rear and, in some cases, to the side.

[image: Horse with Blinkers]

> Blinkers are usually made of leather or plastic cups that are placed on either side of the eyes, either attached to a bridle or to an independent hood. Blinkers that have a peep hole cut in the back of the cup are known as visors.

Answer (score 1):

According to a slideshow at [Daily Racing Form](http://www.drf.com/slideshows/five-different-types-blinkers), there are (at least) five types of **blinkers** in use in U.S. horse racing: **French cup**, **full cup**, **semi cup**, **cheaters**, and **extension cup**. All five types attach to hoods that the horse wear during a race.

**Cheekpieces** are another option for obscuring parts of the horse's range of vision. There is a very nice picture of a horse wearing a cheekpiece, at the top of the article "[Headgear and the Racehorse: Seeing the Wood from the Trees](http://trainermagazine.com/articles/2015/3/27/headgear-and-the-racehorse-seeing-the-wood-from-the-trees)" at TrainerMagazine.com.

A third piece of vision-limiting equipment is the [**shadow roll**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_roll), which attaches to the horse's noseband and makes it harder for the horse to see shadows on the ground in front of it.