# Name of an accessory put on horses that helps them avoid distraction

Tags: single-word-requests

It's a kind of mask that is worn by horses so that they can't see sideways or backwards.

I think it's called a *blinder* (not sure though) but is there a proper term for this accessory in English? Preferably something that is used by Race Organizers?

**Update 1** : The definition I found from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blinder)

> A screen attached to a horse's bridle preventing it from being able to see things to its side.

My question - Does a blinder have other names? (For example, blinker is one...)

**Update 2** : Possible [duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254998) flag raised. I felt that *blinders* were more of a colloquial term(It's my personal view and I may well be wrong). I was looking for a formal term, if there was one.

Comment: Yes, blinders. They're also called blinkers. What did you find in the dictionary entry for "blinder(s)"? That seems like a good starting point.

Comment: @sumelic - I did find *blinders* and its definition to be appropriate. But I was not sure if it had some other name in racing parlance.

Comment: @sumelic - Question updated. Since *blinder* also meant exceptional performance (in UK), I was not very sure. Hope I am doing things right in ELU. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks for updating! It looks like Wiktionary also lists one more synonym that I hadn't heard before – *winkers*.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy A picture of what you're looking for might help...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I have added a clarification. If that doesn't convince you or other moderators, please feel free to remove the question.

Comment: I've only ever heard them called "blinkers" or "blinders".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In British English they are called *blinkers* (also used figuratively). I believe I have read that in American they are *blinders*.

**Edit**: The OED has:

- **blinkers** 2b) "Leather screens attached to a horse's bridle on each side, to prevent his seeing in any direction except straight ahead."
- **blinder** 2) "A blinker for a horse. ... Usu. *pl.* (Chiefly in U.S.)"

Comment: I assume there are no other words to describe it, am I right?

Comment: I suspect the metaphorical use of 'blinkered' is commoner than the original. Also: "*Usu*. pl."?? What use would a single one be?

Answer (score 4):

[***Shadow roll***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_roll) is commonly used in horse racing which means:

> a piece of equipment usually made of sheepskin or a synthetic material, that is attached to
>   the noseband of a horse's bridle. ***Like blinkers***, it partially
>   ***restricts the horse's vision, and helps him to concentrate*** on what is
>   in front of him, rather than objects on the ground (such as shadows).

[Wikipedia]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

***blinker hood*** is the term you're after. [Google Pictures](https://www.google.fr/search?biw=578&bih=380&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=-_BvVq--JMOZUf6ln_gI&q=%22blinker+hood%22&btnG=)

> [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkers_(horse_tack)#British_blinder)

Per comment on Horse&Hound, *blinkers let you see, but only with a very narrow focus, so you can't see the "Big Picture." In racing, it's for horses not to be able to see horses coming up behind them.* [Horse&Hound](http://www.horseandhound.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?614445-Blinders-or-Blinkers-and-which-one-is-American)

And so, the mask worn by race horses so they can't see sideways or backward is a blinker hood (commonly referred to as ***blinkers***)

> blinker: a cloth hood with shades projecting at the sides of the eye openings used on skittish racehorses —**usually used in plural** [M-W](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blinker)
>
> blinder (*esp. AmEng*); blinker (*esp. BrEng*): either of two flaps on a horse's bridle to keep it from seeing objects at its sides [M-W](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blinder)

Answer (score 1):

Those are usually called **Blinders** in the US, and **Blinkers** in the UK, they are sometimes known as **Winkers**, if you want to be sure on what you're talking about when referring to it, use **Blinders** in the US and **Blinkers** in the rest of the speaking English world.